# How to add new Panel in the same Applet using ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I have an applet which has a Panel. In the Panel a button is added which on clicking will remove the current Panel and a new Panel will be added to the current Applet.

But I am not getting the desired output !!!

**I want to replace the Display Panel currently added to the Applet by a new Panel from a ActionListener.**

Kindly tell the mistake !!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Init extends JApplet {

    public Display ref;
    public NewDisplay ref2;

    public class Display extends JPanel  implements ActionListener {

        public Display() {
            initComponents();
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton1.setText("New Game");
            add(jButton1);
            jButton1.addActionListener(this);

        }
        public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String x = e.getActionCommand();
            if (x.equals("New Game")) {
                System.out.println("clicked");
                //ref.setVisible(false);
                this.removeAll();
                //add(ref2);
                add(ref2);
                invalidate();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public class NewDisplay extends JPanel {

        public NewDisplay() {
            setSize(800, 600);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        ref = new Display();
        ref2 = new NewDisplay();
        add(ref);
        setSize(800,600);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you narrowed down the problem? For instance:  Does it get to the actionPerformed() method? Does it output "clicked"?

Comment: Yes, it outputs "Clicked" !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NOT be using the setSize() method to set the size of a component.

Layout managers use the preferred size of the component. You should be overriding the getPreferredSzie() method of your panel to returnthe desired size.

```
public class NewDisplay extends JPanel {

    public NewDisplay() {
    //   setSize(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    }
}
```

Or a better solution is to use a Card Layout and just sway the panels in and out. See [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: I think that every time I read a question on Swing that mentions a Layout, everyone's answer is "a better solution is to use <my preferred Layout> !"  :-)

Comment: In this code we are removing the component of the current panel and adding the new panel to the current panel !!
Is this right ??

Comment: If Yes, How can i remove the current Panel and add a new Panel to the Applet ? Please Clarify !!

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot sir, Please answer my query !!

Comment: @Snehasish: I am not the author of the answer here.  Your use of multiple exclamation marks makes you come across as if you are shouting demands at people.  If you don't understand the answer or it's not working, why did you accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to address Camickr but by mistake addressed you.

Comment: @camickr sir, please answer my query.

Comment: I did answer your question. I gave you a link to the tutorial on using a CardLayout.